# Working with strings in C# using indexing like in F#

Tags: c#, string, indexof

In F# you can do this:

```
let someString = "string"
printfn "%A" someString.[1..]  // will print "tring"
printfn "%A" someString.[1..4] // will print "trin"
printfn "%A" someString.[0]    // will print "s"
```

I rather miss being able to work with strings like that. So my question is if there is something similar in C#?

If not then what do people do in C# when they have a very long  string which they need to extract a specific information from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary method you are looking for is `String.Substring` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx))

In your example, the code would be:

```
string someString = "string";
Console.WriteLine(someString.Substring(1));
Console.WriteLine(someString.Substring(1, 4));
```

You can also access individual characters by index, so the final line would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(someString[0]);
```

To your final question, most of my development experience does not require dealing with long strings like this. Typically such long strings are some kind of object notation and we will use the correct serializer to get an object representation of the string that is much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
          string input = "STACKOVERFLOW";

         // Get first three characters.
         string first= input.Substring(0, 3);
         Console.WriteLine( sub);
```